# Objects visualization

Tags: javascript, html

For some time now I have been meaning to improve the visualization on the web of some surfaces. So far, I record an animation (say on Matlab or Julia) which I upload online. Rather, I would love to use javascript (with WebGL or other if you have a suggestion?) to call it in my index.html file.

To be more precise, suppose I have three 2D arrays `X,Y,Z` which represent a surface. The goal would be to have a javascript code (unless there is a better solution) to visualize the surface and say allow for 3D rotations.

Unfortunately I have no experience with the language and more generally not much knowledge in visualization. In particular, I was unable to adapt the "rotating cube" example of WebGL for my needs...

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to accomplish this? If there is a slicker way of achieving this I am all ears :)

Comment: What code have you written already? Please have a read of [this guide on producing code for a good quality question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), then include and mark up your code in your question. Cheers!

Comment: I did not post any code on purpose for two reasons: there is no code to display, and I am wondering what would be a good workflow. Perhaps some mathematicians around here experienced this and could give a feedback on what they ended up doing/using :).